# Full text search wont find post codes "NNx" where "x" is a digit

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a string with a post code `NN2 7DG`. SQL Server can perfectly find `7DG` but not `NN2`.

My stop words list is empty.

I looked at the indexed keywords and `NN2` is not even there, while `7DG` is

```
-- list indexed keywords
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords (DB_ID('MyDatabase'), OBJECT_ID('MyTable'))
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welp, I found the answer here, only minutes after posting:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8592ea09-fcfb-4fec-a3a4-5e03dedcee3a/problem-with-strings-starting-with-nn-a-number?forum=sqlsearch

> This is because of the way that numbers are stored in the full-text indexes.
>
> - Indexed numbers such as "123" are stored in the fulltext index as "NN123".
> - This behavior is controlled by the wordbreakers.
>
> So, i think that there is little that you can do about this except work around it.

P.S. Wow, just wow...

Comment: I know 0 to none when it comes to the Full Text Search feature so forgive me if this is unhelpful, but is it possible that [altering the word breaker and / or noise words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-word-breakers-and-stemmers-for-search?view=sql-server-ver16) may be what you're looking for? (P.s. I'm a fan of the software, thanks for that.)